# Image crop not working correctly

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, memorystream

The snippet of code is supposed to crop an image, however the size of the crop is correct, but the crop starts at the top left corner. These images illustrate the problem more clearly [image: here] and [image: here].

The co-ordinates are approximately:x=68, y=28, width=176, height=174.  Below is the cropping code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the Click event of the UploadButton control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
/// <remarks></remarks>
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\";


    Boolean FileOK = false;
    Boolean FileSaved = false;

    if (Upload.HasFile)
    {
        Session["WorkingImage"] = Upload.FileName;

        String FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Session["WorkingImage"].ToString()).ToLower();

        String[] allowedExtensions = { ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".gif" };

        for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (FileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
            {
                FileOK = true;
            }
        }
    }


    if (FileOK)
    {
        try
        {
            Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + Session["WorkingImage"]);
            FileSaved = true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "File could not be uploaded." + ex.Message;
            ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            FileSaved = false;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
        ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
    }


    if (FileSaved)
    {
        UploadPanel.Visible = false;
        CropPanel.Visible = true;
        CropImage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + Session["WorkingImage"];
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the Click event of the CropButton control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
/// <remarks></remarks>
protected void CropButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Images\\";

    string ImageName = Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();
    int w = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(W.Value));
    int h = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(H.Value));
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(X.Value));
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(Y.Value));


    byte[] CropImage = Crop(path + ImageName, w, h, x, y);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length);

        using (Image CroppedImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true))
        {
            string SaveTo = path + "crop" + ImageName;
            CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);
            CropPanel.Visible = false;
            CroppedPanel.Visible = true;
            this.CroppedImage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/crop" + ImageName;
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region Methods

/// <summary>
/// Crops the specified image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">The image.</param>
/// <param name="width">The width.</param>
/// <param name="height">The height.</param>
/// <param name="x">The x value.</param>
/// <param name="y">The y value.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <remarks></remarks>
private static byte[] Crop(string image, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        using (Image OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(image))
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
            {
                //bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);

                using (Graphics Graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    //Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), x, -y, width, height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);

                    return ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: There's absolutely no point in catching an exception only to re-throw it. And to make matters worse `throw e;` will actually replace the original call stack.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen true, although to be honest, I copied and pasted, and did not worry about that, but thanks for noting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crop doesn't look like it is starting at the top left corner, just near the top left corner. What it looks like to me is that the `x` and `y` coordinates are wrong. I recommend manually inserting your own `x` and `y` values until you get the image that you want, and then figuring out why the `x` and `y` values differ from what you expect.

I compared it to some cropping code that I have (and that I know works), and I don't see any issues with your actual `Crop` method.

Comment: good observation, I see it is indeed not starting exactly at the top left corner.

Comment: It turns out that the image when being displayed is set at say 200 * 200px, when its real size may be much bigger. JCrop gets the co-ords off the img element, but the c# code acts on the actual image. So I had to get calculate the ratios of the img element vs the actual image, and then compensate the JCrop values. i.e. there was a scaling issue of sorts.